# Is there a JAXB annotation to do this?

Tags: java, serialization, jaxb

Im using JAXB to serialize my Java model, in JAXB you can choose between an `@XmlElement` or an `@XmlAttribute`

my model looks like:

```
public class Link {
    String rel;
    String href;
}
```

If I annotate the properties in the Link class with @XmlAttribute the link will look like

```
<link rel="self" href="http://mycompany.com/resource?param=blah" />
```

if I annotate the properties with `@XmlElement` the link will look like:

```
<link>
    <rel>self</rel>
    <href>http://mycompany.com/resource?param=blah</href>
</link>
```

I have a requirement to make the XML look like this, which is sort of a mix, but I don't want the href tags around the url so using `@XmlElement` for href won't work:

```
<link rel="self">http://mycompany.com/resource?param=blah</link>
```

Is there a way to do this using JAXB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `@XmlValue` for this use case.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Link {

    @XmlAttribute
    String rel;

    @XmlValue
    String href;

}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/jaxb-and-complex-types-with-simple.html